# Tank Tread Mathematical Model

Tags: vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

I am struggiling with tank tread behaviour. The tank treads moving indivually  if I move only the left tread the tank will go to the right direction for sure it depends on tread’s speed value subatraction , if ı am not wrong.

İf the left track moves 50 km and right track  moves with 40km tank will go to the right direction but if i decrease the right track speed around 30 tank has to turn right again but Which Angle ?

When I drive a tank 90 degree forward with remote control I want to turn left 5 degree how much speed difference should be realize to turn 5 degree or 45 degree or 275 degree ?

I tried to put 2 force on a stick which is show the lenght of 2 tread distance. The net force should be locate somewhere on this lenght. It is easy to find if i know the force value.

By the way I tried to imagine with tread’s speed. Tank treads must have angular speed respectively.  How can i associate with turning angle between angular speed or do you have another view!

Comment: You need to work out the moment generated by the difference in tread velocities. That’s what causes the tank to pivot about some point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Calling

$$
\cases{
r = \text{Tread's wheel radius}\\
d = \text{mid tread's front distance}\\
\vec v_i = \text{Wheels center velocities}
}
$$

assuming the whole set as a rigid body, we can apply the Poisson kinematics law.

$$
\vec v_1 \times(p_1-O) = \vec v_2 \times(p_2-O)
$$

where $p_i$ are application points and $O$ is the rotation instantaneous center. Calling $G$ the arrangement geometrical center, $\vec V = V(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $p_G = (x_G,y_G)$ we have the equivalent kinematics

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x_G\\
\dot y_G\\
\dot\theta
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & 0\\
\sin\theta & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
V\\
\omega
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and also

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
V\\
\omega
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac r2 & \frac r2\\
\frac{r}{2d} &-\frac{r}{2d}\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\omega_1\\
\omega_2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Here $\omega$ is the rigid body angular rotation velocity, $\omega_i$ is the wheels angular rotation velocity. Assuming that the wheels do not skid laterally, should be considered the following restriction of movement:

$$
\dot x_G\sin\theta +\dot y_G\cos\theta = d_0\dot\theta
$$

where $d_0$ is the distance between $p_G$ and the tread center. This is a rough qualitative approximation. The real tank kinematics are a lot more complex.

NOTE

Attached a MATHEMATICA script simulating the movement kinematics.

```
parms = {r -> 0.5, d -> 2, d0 -> 0.1, wr -> UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - 30], wl -> UnitStep[t - 10] - 2 UnitStep[t - 50]};
M = {{Cos[theta[t]], 0}, {Sin[theta[t]], 0}, {0, 1}};
D0 = {{r/2, r/2}, {r/(2 d), -r/(2 d)}};
equs = Thread[D[{x[t], y[t], theta[t]}, t] == M.D0.{wr, wl}];
equstot = equs /. parms;
cinits = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, theta[0] == 0};
tmax = 100;
solmov = NDSolve[Join[equstot, cinits], {x, y, theta}, {t, 0,tmax}][[1]];
gr0 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. solmov], {t, 0,tmax}];
car[x_, y_, theta_, e_] := Module[{p1, p2, p3, bc, M, p1r, p2r, p3r},
  p1 = {0, e};
  p2 = {2 e, 0};
  p3 = {0, -e};
  bc = (p1 + p2 + p3)/3;
  M = RotationMatrix[theta];
  p1r = M.(p1 - bc) + {x, y};
  p2r = M.(p2 - bc) + {x, y};
  p3r = M.(p3 - bc) + {x, y};
  Return[{p1r, p2r, p3r, p1r}]
]
nshots = 100;
dt = Floor[tmax/nshots];
path0 = Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], theta[t]} /. solmov];
path = Table[path0 /. {t -> k dt}, {k, 0, Floor[tmax/dt]}];
grpath = Table[ListLinePlot[car[path[[k, 1]], path[[k, 2]],path[[k, 3]], 0.2], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], {k, 1, Length[path]}];
Show[gr0, grpath, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank yo so much.I feel pain in my brain :) In this case I have to know that geometrical center and vectorel velocity but it doesnt make sense for me. I’m going to code that equation in my RC tank to control with joystick. There are so many unknown in equation. I dont know teta degree and I should know teta  to solve your equ. Will Teta give tank direction angle degree  ? If the tank doesnt move at the begining and user want to give direction to tank , what will happen ? And can you provide a example to determine gx gy because Geometrical center coordinate wont be change for a rigid object.

Comment: @emir Attached a MATHEMATICA script simulating the movement kinematics